# Application is crashing on Android 10 while downloading video files using DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager

App crashes while setting `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()`

```
 val videoDir = Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath + "/applicationfiles/.tutorial"
downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(videoDir, videoName)
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: app.package, PID: 19275
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not one of standard directories: /data/applicationfiles/.tutorial
>           at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2079)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
>           at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
>           at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
>           at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:658)
>           at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:558)
>           at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:546)
>           at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:569)
>           at app.package.startDownloadingFile(ExerciseTutorialPresenter.kt:159)
>           at app.package.downloadVideoFiles(ExerciseTutorialPresenter.kt:142)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(dirType: String!, subPath: String!)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setdestinationinexternalpublicdir)

For applications targeting Android 10 and above, the first parameter `dirType` for this method must be one of the known public directories like `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`, `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`, `Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES`, etc.

Comment: okay, then what if I don't want to expose the downloaded file and I am using, Environment.getDataDirectory() path for download?

Comment: For the question I had asked, you are correct that Android 10 accepts only known public directories. And for other folders like "data/data" we can use downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, filePath, fileName)